# Nested if condition in kendo grid column template

Tags: javascript, if-statement, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

While trying to implement condition function in kendo grid column template, there is a problem happening, data from my grid are not shown, my function is

```
function material() {
  if (PCommonPortalMethods.GetSiteLanguage() == 'en') {
    if (data.Unit._Key) {
      Unit.UnitGlobalName
    }
    else ('')
  }
  else {
    if (data.Unit._Key) {
      Unit.UnitLocalName
    }
    else ('')
  }
}
```

and I call it from template like :         `template:'#= material() #'`

I tried something like that also:

```
template: "#if (PCommonPortalMethods.GetSiteLanguage() == 'en') {# if(data.Unit._Key) #=Unit.UnitGlobalName#  else(" ") #} else { # if(data.Unit._Key) #=Unit.UnitLocalName#  else(" ") #} #"
```

can someone help me? what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `return` inside of it, change your script like this

```
function material() {
  if (PCommonPortalMethods.GetSiteLanguage() === 'en') {
    if (data.Unit._Key) {
      return Unit.UnitGlobalName;
    }
    return '';
  }
  else {
    if (data.Unit._Key) {
        return Unit.UnitLocalName;
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

or we could change your script like this

```
function material() {
  var text = '';

  if(data.Unit._key) {
    text = PCommonPortalMethods.GetSiteLanguage() === 'en' ? 
              Unit.UnitGlobalName : Unit.UnitLocalName;
  }

  return text;
}
```

Simple yet still readable, if you like to make a script template it could be like this.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    # if (PCommonPortalMethods.GetSiteLanguage() === 'en') { #
    #    if(data.Unit._Key) { #
    <span> #= Unit.UnitGlobalName # </span>
    #    } #
    #} else { # 
    #    if(data.Unit._Key) {#
    <span> #= Unit.UnitLocalName # </span>
    #    } #
    # } #
</script>
```

and use it like this

```
template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
```

Comment: if I use it in template, do I need to define those variables somehow? because I always get an error that something is undefined